# How to schedule an intent for later in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, scheduled-tasks, android-broadcast

I've just started Android development and encountered this problem. I'm trying to start an Intent after a specific time.

1. I tried using a runnable and a handler.postAtTime method by putting the Intent in the Runnable. This method does nothing when u destroy the application or restart the phone.
2. I tried setting up a BroadcastReceiver but it won't allow me to use the startActivity(Intent) for the Intent. I tried using the Context.startActivity(Intent), but it made the app stop working if its destroyed before the Intent is completed.

Can anybody help me out with the same? Thanks.

Edit1 :

Here's the BroadcastReceiver I call using an AlarmManager:

```
package com.mallock.sch_email2;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO); 
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Activity1.subj);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Activity1.body);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:".concat(Activity1.rec)));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(arg0,intent);
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
07-15 21:43:13.980    4569-4569/com.mallock.sch_email2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mallock.sch_email2, PID: 4569
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.mallock.sch_email2.Broadcast: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2580)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.lang.String.concat(String.java:678)
            at com.mallock.sch_email2.Broadcast.onReceive(Broadcast.java:16)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2573)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code you've written, it's almost always helpful to show what you've worked on so far, even if you've explained the approaches.

Comment: @Akshat I forgot to add flag in intent inside receiver. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: The logcat is showing that the 'Activity1.rec' field is null which concat doesn't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using PendingIntent.getBroadcast and then used the BroadcastReceiver to start an Intent. Directly using PendingIntent.getActivity solved the issue.

@Mimmo Grottoli: Right on... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

To perform an event in future at specific time you need to use **AlarmManager** class .

For Example If you want to open an activity after 2 hours then:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReciever.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

am.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 7200000 , pendingIntent );
```

**Receiver::::**

```
public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(
                  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you send the intent to a broadcast, and from the broadcast to a Activity? You can send the intent to the Activity directly

Comment: i did exactly that, and i initialized a new intent in the BroadcastReceiver. Thereafter i called on the context.startActivity(Intent) method. It causes the program to crash.

Maybe its because i passed the MainActivity.this as Context and BroadcastReceiver calls on the startActivity method of a destroyed application?

Comment: Also, i might add here that simply startActivity is not recognised from the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Why you don't use PendingIntent.getActivity to send the intent to the Activity? You need same flags of course.

Answer (score 1):

This [class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is for you! The AlarmManager is the right way to go.